# appending xml data in between nodes using php

Tags: php, xml

```
  $employees = array(); 
  $employees [] = array( 
  'name' => 'Albert', 
  'age' => '34', 
  'salary' => "$1000000000" 
  ); 
  $employees [] = array( 
  'name' => 'Claud', 
  'age' => '20', 
  'salary' => "$200000000" 
  ); 

  $doc = new DOMDocument(); 
  $doc->load('xml/text.xml');
  $doc->formatOutput = true; 

  $r = $doc->createElement( "employees" ); 
  $doc->appendChild( $r ); 

  foreach( $employees as $employee ) 
  { 
  $b = $doc->createElement( "employee" ); 

  $name = $doc->createElement( "name" ); 
  $name->appendChild( 
  $doc->createTextNode( $employee['name'] ) 
  ); 
  $b->appendChild( $name ); 

  $age = $doc->createElement( "age" ); 
  $age->appendChild( 
  $doc->createTextNode( $employee['age'] ) 
  ); 
  $b->appendChild( $age ); 

  $salary = $doc->createElement( "salary" ); 
  $salary->appendChild( 
  $doc->createTextNode( $employee['salary'] ) 
  ); 
  $b->appendChild( $salary ); 

  $r->appendChild( $b ); 
  } 


  $doc->save("xml/text.xml")
```

this existing code load and writes data to an xml file, however right now it keeps creating the parent node "employees" over and over again. How would I just append the child nodes to the already existing employees node in the xml file?

Comment: Is there only one `employees` node in the document originally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your root node isn't `employees`, and that there is just one `employees` node, replace these lines:

```
$r = $doc->createElement('employees');
$doc->appendChild( $r );
```

With these:

```
$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('employees');
if ($tags->length) {
    $r = $tags->item(0);
} else {
    $r = $doc->createElement('employees');
    $doc->appendChild( $r );
}
```

This code uses the first `employees` node found in the document. If none is found, it appends one to the end of the document. Actually, I'm guessing you want to insert the employees node somewhere inside the document, instead of at the end....

Comment: yes there should be only employees. then all the child nodes go inside like employee etc..

Comment: what if I just want one node with attributes?

Comment: @Adam I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "one node with attributes." Do you mean one `employee` node per person, with name, age, and salary as attributes? If so, you'd do something like `$b->setAttribute('name', $employee['name']);`

Comment: You might want to check out the docs at http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php; Also, you may consider using SimpleXML instead of DOMDocument: http://php.net/simplexml

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have an XML structure in xml/text.xml with a root node of 'employees' you want to replace this line:

```
$r = $doc->createElement( 'employees' );
```

with this line:

```
$r = $doc->documentElement;
```